# Replacement draft inducer motor stopped working after 3 months

Tags: hvac, furnace

My Goodman GMNT060-3 furnace stopped turning on in October. The tech diagnosed a bad draft inducer motor, because the fan wouldn't spin freely and made a grinding noise when turned by hand. I replaced the motor myself with a new one from eBay - a FASCO Inducer Motor 77-161-000. It worked well for a couple of months, but recently it started making rattling noises while the fan was spinning.

Today, the furnace stopped turning on altogether. I pulled out the 3-month-old draft inducer motor and turned the fan by hand. It feels just like the old motor's fan did - not spinning freely at all. I replaced the motor and got the furnace started again by manually turning the fan, but obviously that's a short-term fix.

**What could cause a draft motor to go from like-new operation to dead within a few months?** Could the eBay motor have been a dud? Or is something else wrong?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's unlikely we could tell from here. That said, if a type of part fails (prematurely?) once, it isn't an enormous surprise if another one fails as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it could be a dud.  These things are mass produced.  Even good companies (FASCO) will turn out a dud occasionally.  Keep in mind that fan is subject to horrible heat contamination.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a dud. Make sure you get a replacement with warranty. Check your voltage at the motor. Also if your furnace is oversized repeated starts and stops are very hard on ventor motors.